# a dispatch that im trying to push into an array is calling it instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple custom hook with a few dispatches and callbacks on them.

It looks something like this:

```
const { updateText, updateImage, updateTitle, batchJobs } = useBlock();
```

This is called a larger component that props open a big edit window. Upon making those changes, I click my confirmation button that does something similar to this:

```
   const onConfirm = () => {
        let toDispatch = [];
        // some logic
        toDispatch.push(updateText(id, text)); // this gets called right away
        console.log(toDispatch); // this is undefined or null
        batchEdit(toDispatch);
    }
```

It seems that my `updateText` dispatch is being called right when I try to push it, as it does do its job. But that is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Within `batchEdit` I want to loop through all the function and call them, then upon completion I call a callback that updates the screen. I can never get into to it as the array is always becoming `undefined`.

Comment: `updateText.bind(this, id, text)`

Comment: What are you expecting to store in toDispatch??

Comment: @danronmoon how do you call the function from the array upon using it?

Comment: Are you expecting to store the function? or the value returned by calling the function?

Comment: @lissettdm I want to store the function, then within the batchEdit function I want to iterate through the array and useDisptach on each other stored functions (along with their data)

Comment: In that case @Tomasz Kisiel answers your question

Comment: @Robolisk just invoke it without any arguments (it has stored reference to id and text passed from `bind`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you want to pass your function does not give it, but only adds the value returned by the function to the array. To pass function ( not returned value ) you should create callback.

```js
toDispatch.push(() => updateText(1, "sss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`func test()` will call the function. To treat function as Lambda (data) you need to just use the the name so you need to change the 4th line to this:
 `toDispatch.push(updateText, id, text)`